# WKInterfaceTable add scroll bar "flash' and remove scroll bar from non-scrolling view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, watchkit, watchos-2

I have two questions regarding WatchKit:

1) I have an app that uses [WKInterfaceTable]. One of the interfaces is scrollable.As such, when the user scrolls, the scroll bar appears in the top right corner of the watch interface.

How do I get the scroll bar to temporary flash the scroll bar when the user opens the app. A good example  of this functionality is the Calendar app in Apple watch.
I've combed the net and WatchKit catalog (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/WKInterfaceCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) but was not able to find a solution.

2) I have another interface that only shows one row on the watch and therefore does not need to scroll. How do I remove the scroll view in this case?

I am using WatchKit 2.0 and writing the app in Objective-C.

Comment: Given the way that questions are searched for and tracked in SO and external search engines, it might be better to break this up into two questions

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you could get the desired effect by scrolling to the top programmatically after the view has loaded?

`table.scrollToRowAtIndex(0)`

If that didn't work, then perhaps (again after load) scroll to the second row and then back to the first to cause the bar to display?

`table.scrollToRowAtIndex(1)
table.scrollToRowAtIndex(0)`

I haven't tried this, but I have programmatically traveled to rows in a WKInterface table and I believe you do get the scroll bar.